# XmlSerializer output xml types

Tags: c#, binary, xmlserializer

I am using the XmlSerializer, and was wondering if there is any way, using overrides or something to that effect to get the XmlSerializer to output the types of some nodes.

My problem is that I have serialized a byte array.

```
class MyClass {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}
```

I am consuming the xml in a generic service.
The service collects the xml as .

```
<MyClass>
  <Name>Test</Name>
  <Bytes>U2NhcnkgQnVnZ2Vy</Bytes>
</MyClass>
```

Is there any way to either generate an xsd at runtime, or somehow output something like this.

I cannot change the class I am serializing, but I can apply overrides to the serializer or in some other way control the serialization.

```
<Bytes xsi:type='BinaryOfSomeKind'>BlahBlah</Bytes>
```

I need to know that the data is binary somehow.

Thanks

Craig.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem correctly. Are you consuming a XML with always has the same structure but the types of the elements may differ?

Comment: I am converting a class to xml. The class is supplied by a third party. I am taking in the xml and indexing the contents. I need to know which fields are binary. If there is an easy way to generate an xsd I can accept that too. I could supply the code to generate the xsd. Maybe it was a silly question.

Comment: If your class is supplied by a third party then you know your properties and property types and you can deduce your XML from it. You can even create a XSD for it manually.

Comment: I think I will create an xsd manually. I was hoping that there was a class to do the xsd creation already. I will do it manually. If you answer the question with that I will mark it, as that's as close as I will get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class is supplied by a third party then you know your properties and property types and you can deduce your XML and XSD from it. You can create your XSD manually or with the help of a XML tool for example [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/) (not free BTW) or [XMLFox](http://www.xmlfox.com/) which is free of charge.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the xml is going to be in that format that you put in the question and you have your class ready you can decorate it as such for it to be deserialized.

The Deserialization class:

```
[XmlTypeAttribute]
[XmlRootAttribute("MyClass")]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElementAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElementAttribute("Bytes")]
    public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
}
```

The Deserialzation Method

```
 public static object Deserialize(string xml)
 {
        var deserializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
        {
            return (MyClass)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
 }
```

The Main Method

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"<MyClass>
        <Name>Test</Name>
        <Bytes>U2NhcnkgQnVnZ2Vy</Bytes>
         </MyClass>";

        MyClass obj = (MyClass)Deserialize(xml);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Make sure to add the following using statements:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
```

It deserialized it into an obj with "Test" as the byte array.

If you generate the XSD at run time, then theres no way you can know what properties there are and it would be down to using reflection to test for specific properties, and then subsequently finding out what types they may be, is this what your after?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that's not going to work. I don't have the format. I need to know that the string is binary. I need to add the type to the outgoing xml or generate a schema or write my own serializer. Your solution will not suffice. I am well aware that the serializer works if I know its binary but I don't.

Comment: So you are trying to control how `MyClass` is Serialized, but you can't decorate the class at all. But you need to output it in the format you describe? is that right?

Comment: I can decorate the class with any attributes as they can be passed to the serializer in the overrides. I can generate an xsd. I can reflect over the class I can serialize the class. I just need to know what the xml type of the binary fields is. I think I am going to drop the serializer and use reflection. I cannot change the class. The class is supplied by a third party.